# GoogleCloudOptions doesn't have all options that <pipeline>.options has

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So my beam job today ended up with this warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py:800: BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to .options will not be supported

So as I understood, instead of doing this:

```
self.options = {'project': self.project_name,
               'job_name': self.job_name,
               }
```

I will have to move to this:

```
self.options = PipelineOptions()
        google_cloud_options = self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
        google_cloud_options.project = self.project_name
        google_cloud_options.job_name = self.job_name
```

But there is a problem, a lot of options are not available anymore, e.g. max number worker, setup file location...

I tried to go through its documentation again but couldn't find what are the replacements for those missing fields.

If I just added to the new GoogleCloudOptions some registered label, it will complain:

> AttributeError: 'GoogleCloudOptions' object has no attribute
>   'max_num_workers'

So does anyone know what are the replacements for those fields?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some of the options have been moved to `WorkerOptions` in the same module of the Apache Beam SDK library.

Comment in the `WorkerOptions` class:

> Command line options controlling the worker pool configuration.

It includes `num_workers`, `max_num_workers`, `worker_machine_type`, and a few more that I believe have been in `GoogleCloudOptions` before.

See this link for the module's source as of v2.12: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.12.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html#WorkerOptions